# iframe связка с родителем

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Есть модальное окно в него вставлен Фрейм.
Во фрейме отображается карточка.
При сохранении карточки нужно:
1) Сохранить карточку
2) Закрыть модальное окно

окно взял [Отсюда](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2011/02/modalnoe-okno-css.html#showimagelink)

пример 2.

закрытие карточки реализовано в карточке

```
<a id=\"button\" href='?$_SESSION[table]#showimagelink' target=\"_parent\">x</a>
```

и отдельно есть кнопка sumbit которая выполняет сохранение карточки.
вопрос как завязать всю эту дрянь на 1 кнопку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) При создании модального окна придумайте ему id.
2) Передайте этот id в фрейм (например, через $_GET).
3) При сохранении во фрейме проверяйте:

```
if(window != window.parent) window.parent.closeThisDialog(__id__);
```